# Zurb Foundation Nested Div Issue

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

So I'm just getting my head around Foundation at the moment...and I'm having issues with how nested divs work.

I have a grid with 14 columns...I want to center my content by having a large-12 centered div and then divide up my content within that...What I'm trying to figure out is...do I have a total of 12 columns inside that div...or does it reset to 14 columns inside of my 12 column width div?

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="large-12 large-centered columns">

      <div class="large-5 columns" style="background-color:#CCC;">
          <img class="logo" src="img/360logo.png">
      </div>

      <div class="large-8 large-offset-1 columns nav" style="background-color:#CCC;">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#" class="nav last">Become a Model</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="nav first">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      </div>

   </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why do you only want to use 12 columns of the 14 column layout?

Are you wanting to leave a spare column on the left and right?


For any div.row, you need to reuse 14 columns inside that.

In their first example in the docs,  see how within every .row, the numbers add up to 12: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Answer (score 0):

You will have 14 columns. It is the same for any nested row no matter how deep you go.